# Ошибка при обращении к ГУИ с использованием Dispatcher

Tags: c#, wpf

Хотел запустить анимацию грида из другого потока, но получил ошибку, что не могу обратиться к элементу из этого потока. Юзал Dispatcher.BeginInvoke, но все равно не работает. Как мне заставить решить эту проблему? Вот вызываемый метод:

```
    public void DisplayInfo(User user)
    {
        double duration = 0.175;
        Thickness old = new Thickness(0, -80, 0, 0);
        Thickness to = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
        ThicknessAnimation animation = new ThicknessAnimation();
        animation.From = old;
        animation.To = to;
        animation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(duration);
        //Вот тут ошибка
        UserGrid.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate () { UserGrid.BeginAnimation(MarginProperty, animation); }));
    }
```

Comment: Что за UserGrid и откуда у него диспетчер? Вы же в курсе, что диспетчеров может быть несколько (так как диспетчер можно создать в не-UI потоке)? Попробуйте `System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher`

Comment: @tym32167 Обычный wpf grid

Comment: Попробуйте то, что я предложил

Comment: @tym32167 Не сработало
System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate () { UserGrid.BeginAnimation(MarginProperty, animation); }));

Comment: зачем запускать анимацию из другого потока?

Comment: Возможно сообщение выскакивает потому, что сама анимация создана в другом потоке. Запустите в диспетчере весь метод, а не только последнюю строчку

Comment: @tym32167 Да, помогло, почему-то сразу не подумал об этом, спасибо!